# Adwhirl's reporting doesn't show chart

Tags: amazon-ec2, adwhirl

I set up an Adwhirl Server at Amazon EC2. Everything is working fine, except Adwhirl's reporting. The Adwhirl's reporting doesn't show chart and reports. But I got some reports from my Ad networks.

Here is some strange logs in my Adwhirl Server

04:38:07,390 ERROR RollupDaemon:97 - Impressions found: 0
04:40:07,260 ERROR RollupDaemon:97 - Impressions found: 0
04:42:07,302 ERROR RollupDaemon:97 - Impressions found: 0
04:44:07,338 ERROR RollupDaemon:97 - Impressions found: 0
04:46:07,378 ERROR RollupDaemon:97 - Impressions found: 0

Could you please help to fix this problem?
Thank you so much

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix the issue.  In general though, AdWhirl's reporting is not very reliable anyways, and you are better off looking at the individual ad network reporting anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old but I figured it may be helpful to someone.

The reason reporting doesn't work out of the box is due to the fact that the adwhirl image does not include fusion charts, because of licensing with Fusions Charts.

To get this working just upload the fusion chart demo to:
/root/adwhirl-servers-website/www.adwhirl.com/FusionCharts

and it should just start to work. Note this folder should contain all of the swf files.